# How to count more than one distinct columns in linq to sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am struggling with Linq, hence it is a lame question but still ..
I have a table with following 4 columns

```
Pid   SKU    colorid   sizeid
1     'A65102'    38       2
2     'A65102'    38       4
3     'A65102'    38       18
```

I have to get how many different color and size option are available for this.

In sql, I use to do it by:

```
select count(distinct [sizeid]) ,count(distinct [colors]) 
from [item_master] 
where sku = 'A65102'
```

But in Linq, I can get all the values by

```
var dd = (from im in db.item_masters 
          where im.sku.Contains("A65102") 
          select new {im.sizeid,im.colors });
```

But how can I get the count of distinct values for both in single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy`:

```
var distinctCounts = db.item_masters.GroupBy(im => im.sku)
    .Where(grp => grp.Key == "A65102")
    .Select(grp => new { 
        CntSizes  =  grp.Select(im => im.sizeid).Distinct().Count(),
        CntColors =  grp.Select(im => im.colorid).Distinct().Count()
    });
```

Comment: What is the key here .Where(grp => grp.Key == "A65102") rest I can understand. You answer is write gives the correct result, but please elaborate so that I understand how it is being achieved.

Comment: @Ratna: `Enumerable.GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` which has a property `Key` which maps to the property  that you used for grouping, in this case `sku`. The group can contain multiple records but they all share the same group-key `"A65102"`. You could also use the other way round: `Where(im => im.sku == "A65102").GroupBy(im => im.sku)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the query that you have as a data source for retrieving this data (especially useful if you would want to use it for other things as well afterwards):

```
var dd = (from im in db.item_masters 
          where im.sku == "A65102" 
          select new {im.sizeid, im.colors}).ToList();

var numDistinctSizes = dd.Select(x => x.sizeid).Distinct().Count();
var numDistinctColors = dd.Select(x => x.colors).Distinct().Count();
```

Comment: While this  works in this case because the resultset seems to be small it does not really answer the question how to do that in the database. You need two queries instead of one and both are using  Linq-To-Object to query  an in-memory collection. Without the `Where` it's not a viable option to load all into memory.